# BBox strategy without redrawing existing features

Tags: openlayers-3

It seems like with `ol.loadingstrategy.bbox` all existing features get redrawn when panning or zooming. I noticed it because the semi-transparent default polygon fill color becomes more and more opaque after every pan or zoom action. How can I achieve it that only new features are added to the layer without redrawing the existent ones?

Here's my relevant code:

```
var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
  var epsg4326Extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
  var url = 'geojson.php?bbox=' + epsg4326Extent.join(',');
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {        
      var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(data, { dataProjection:'EPSG:4326', featureProjection:'EPSG:3857' });
      vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
      }
    }); 
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});
```

**EDIT:**

It works if the GeoJSON looks like this (see reply by [ahocevar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31255020/5085084)):

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features":
   [
     {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Dinagat Islands"
      }
     },
     {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 2,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [126.05, 9.85]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Siargao"
      }
     }    
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the bbox strategy to work properly, the GeoJSON returned by your server has to set a server unique id as 'id' of each 'Feature' object. Without this, OpenLayers will not know that a feature has already been loaded.